# Check number of rows and delete the last one which is over the limit

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently I am using the following solution to check number of records and then delete the last one of them which is over the limit. Pseudocode:

```
var count = SELECT COUNT(*) AS count FROM table WHERE user_id = ?;

if (count > LIMIT) { // e.g [LIMIT == 5]
    DELETE FROM table WHERE user_id = ? ORDER BY last_activity LIMIT 1;
}
```

The problem however is that I am not happy about this solution. I would like to or rather prefer to do all this using one sql query only.

The type of `last_activity` column is `DATETIME`.

Comment: What's the problem with using subqueries?

Comment: @0101 . . . I'm confused.  Your query *deletes* one row (`limit 1`), but the text says you "have to keep one row".  Which is it?  Keep one or delete one?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that I have to delete one row. Thank you for warning me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `join` in a `delete` statement to delete all but the most recent row, when there are more than five rows for a user:

```
delete t from table t join
              (select user_id, max(last_activity) as mla
               from table
               group by user_id
               having count(*) > 5
              ) mla
              on t.user_id = mla.user_id and
                 t.last_activity < mla.mla;
```

That does it for *all* users.  For one user, add a `where` statement:

```
delete t from table t join
              (select user_id, max(last_activity) as mla
               from table
               where user_id = '?'
               group by user_id
               having count(*) > 5
              ) mla
              on t.user_id = mla.user_id and
                 t.last_activity < mla.mla;
```

EDIT:

To delete one row, just use `min()` instead of `max()`:

```
delete t from table t join
              (select user_id, min(last_activity) as mla
               from table
               where user_id = '?'
               group by user_id
               having count(*) > 5
              ) mla
              on t.user_id = mla.user_id and
                 t.last_activity = mla.mla;
```

Comment: Strongly apologize for confusion, query should delete only one row that has smallest last_activity value so your examples are not working right ,but anyway thank you.

Comment: I have one more question. This query (subquery) selects user_id & last_activity and then is deleted row that is equal to... ,but what if I wanted to select only id instead of user_id and last_activity? Thank you  *I know that it will not make any difference ,but I would like to know how it works. Thanks

Comment: @0101 . . . You could add something like `where userid = (select user_id from table where id = ?)`

Answer (score 0):

To keep everything in a single query, you could use something like this:

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE
  user_id = ?
  AND last_activity = (SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>5 THEN MIN(last_activity) END
    FROM table
    WHERE user_id = ?) s)
```

subquery will return the first `last_activity` if there are more than 5 activities, and the DELETE query will delete it. Otherwise it will return NULL and no row will be deleted.

Comment: If I try this query separately ,so first "SELECT CASE..." query and then "DELETE FROM..." queries are working right ,but together I am getting error "You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause"

Comment: @0101 fixed, it should be okay now